# Decode Base64 text from Legiscan API in R

Tags: r, base64

I am trying to analyze bill texts from LegisScan, but am running into problems decoding the text from the API pull response. Turns out LegisScan encodes the full text of all legislations in base 64 when pulled through their API and I am having some trouble decoding it.

This  [downloaded JSON request](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ozd0a1zsb6y9pi/Legiscan_fulltext?dl=0)  is an example of the full text portion of the JSON result that I downloaded through the API. However, the usual methods do not seem to be working on it.

What I have tried:

1. Legiscan does not seem to support R directly, so I used the package LegiscanR. I used LegiscanR's BillText function to get the correct JSON link, then used parseBillText to try to decode the text from the link into UTF-8. However, it throws up a fromJSON error even with the correct API key and document id stated in the link:

> Error in fromJSON(content, handler, default.size, depth, allowComments,  : 
>     object 'Strict' not found

2. Using the base64decode (base64enc package) or base64Decode (RCurl package) function to convert the text from base 64 to raw, and then using the rawToChar function to convert it into characters.

My code:

```
text <- base64decode("https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ozd0a1zsb6y9pi/Legiscan_fulltext.txt?dl=0")

rawToChar(text)
Nul <- text == as.raw(00)
text[Nul] <- as.raw(20)
text2 <- rawToChar(text)
```

However, trying to use the rawToChar alone gives me an "embedded nul in string" error

> Error in rawToChar(test2) : 
>     embedded nul in string: '%PDF-1.5\r\n%\xb5\xb5\xb5\xb5\r\n1 0 obj\r\n<>>>\r\nendobj\r\n2 0 obj\r\n<>\r\nendobj\r\n3 0 obj\r\n<>/ExtGState<>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 612 792] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>\r\nendobj\r\n4 0 obj\r\n<>\r\nstream\r\nx\x9c\xb5ZYs\xdb8\022~w\x95\xff\003*O\u0516M\021ཛJ\x95\xe3ę̵\x99\xb1\xa7f\xb7\x92y\xa0$\xca\xe2\x86"\025\036\xf6\xe6\xdfow\003\x94\bR0sh\x93*\x99G\xa3\001|\xdd\xfdu7\xa4\xf9U\xd5d\xebdٰ\xe7\xcf\xe7WM\x93,7銽\x9f\u07d5\xbb\xbf\xe6w\x9fw\xe9\xfc]r\x9f\025I\x93\x95\xc5\xfc\xb6]4\xf8\xe8\x874Y\xa5Ջ\027\xec\xe5\xabk\xf6\xf2\xee\xfcl~\xc3Yl\xc7\

Substituting these nulls out to represent spaces allows rawToChar to run, but the output is gibberish, or in another form of encoding that is not the expected English text characters.

> [1] "\x86\xdbi\xb3\xff\xf0\xc3\ak\xa2\x96\xe8\xc5\xca&\xfe\xcf\xf9\xa37tk\\xeco\xac\xbd\xa6/\xcbz\b\xacq\xa9\u07faYm{\033m\xc6\xd7e"

Any other ideas on what else to try? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with the same problem in Python and in Python the following code worked:

```
import base64
raw = base64.b64decode(bill_text['doc'])
pdf_result = open(output_file, "wb").write(raw)
```

I think maybe in your case you are trying to convert the document immediately into text but that may not be so easy and I did in Python by parsing the saved PDF file with functions from the PyPDF2 library.